# Check if UIImageView's image has been changed

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

Ok, so I have a problem where I need to check if the user has changed the image inside and imageView. If no then the app doesn't need to resave a bunch of stuff and it is changed then it should save. So bascically this is just to optimize the code since when saving I am writing four images (loRes, loResThumb, hiRes and hiResthumb) to disk and that takes a little while.

I thought I might try doing it by saving the image as NSDATA when the user enters edit mode and then when the users exits, check and see if the NSDATA contained in the UIIMageView is the same as the one I saved temporarily before. Would that work or is their a better way, like checking if the UIImagePicker has been called (doesn't necessarily mean the image is changed but at least it closer than just saving every time).

Any tips appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you starting with a pre-set default image, that you know would be the same each time?

Comment: No. The user can change the image to whatever he or she wants, which is then saved to disk and then grabbed from disk and inserted into the UIImageView when viewing the specific page again. So I need to know if the user has changed the image that is displayed, regardless of what image was there before. Makes sense?

Comment: Ok so I tried this:                                                This is set when the view is loaded:                      self.oldWishImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.theImageView.image);                And then this is when the users saves his or her changes:                         NSData *currentImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.theImageView.image);
if ([self.oldWishImage isEqualToData:currentImage]) 
 {
  NSLog(@"same picture");
 }
 else
  NSLog(@"new picture");                                 Seems to work...any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a subclass of UIImageView that 'tags' a dirty value if `image` is set.

```
@interface myImageView : UIImageView {
    BOOL _dirty; // set to NO in init
}

- (BOOL) hasChanged;

@end

@implementation


- (void) setImage: (UIImage *)image
{
    [super setImage:image];
    _dirty = YES;
}

- (BOOL) hasChanged
{
   if (!_dirty) return NO;
   _dirty = NO;
   return YES;
}
@end
```